# Is there an R function to filter a dataframe in which columns with all matching values are kept?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large data frame with 5 rows but ~100k columns. I would like to keep columns in which all values within a column match.

This is sample of the dataframe

```
> df
  Mouse JAX00000010 JAX00000010r UNCHS000003 JAX00240606 JAX00240613 JAX00240636 UNCHS000005
1   407          BF           BF          BF          BF          BF          BF          BF
2   410          BH           BH          BH          BH          BH          BH          BH
3   426          BD           BD          BD          BD          BD          BD          BD
4   447          BC           BC          BC          BC          BC          BC          BC
5    87          BF           BF          BF          BF          BF          BF          BF
```

I'd like to keep any columns that all have the same value such as 'BB'. I have not come across a function that does this though I'm sure it's something simple. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the rapid answers. I used the purrr solution by @JasonAizkalns since with my dataframe size the filter function took too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `purrr` approach:

```
library(purrr)
df %>% keep(~ length(unique(.x)) == 1)
```

*N.B. - you can invert this with `discard`: `df %>% discard(~ length(unique(.x)) == 1)`.*

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
df[, sapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1]
```

Or use `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1, df)
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R:

```
# Your data
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
Mouse JAX00000010 JAX00000010r UNCHS000003 JAX00240606 JAX00240613 JAX00240636 UNCHS000005
1   407          BF           BF          BF          BF          BB          BF          BF
2   410          BH           BH          BH          BH          BB          BH          BH
3   426          BD           BD          BD          BD          BB          BD          BD
4   447          BC           BC          BC          BC          BB          BC          BC
5    87          BF           BF          BF          BF          BB          BF          BF")

# Get cols
get.cols <- which(apply(df[,-1] == "BB", 2, all))
df[,c(1, get.cols + 1)]
#  Mouse JAX00240613
#1   407          BB
#2   410          BB
#3   426          BB
#4   447          BB
#5    87          BB
```

**Edit** Oops, I misunderstood the question as a particular search string. If that is not the case and you are looking for columns with only one value, then the following works:

```
get.cols <- which(apply(df, 2, function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1))
df[, c(1, get.cols)]
#  Mouse JAX00240613
#1   407          BB
#2   410          BB
#3   426          BB
#4   447          BB
#5    87          BB
```

Assuming you want the first column outputted as well. If not, then you can of course simplify it a bit.